# How to save this question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

This closed question, and its answer, have proven relevant and useful.

[Jquery Mobile automatically adds &nbsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784062/jquery-mobile-automatically-adds-nbsp)

As I posted in comments, I disagree with most of the close reasons, but I will agree that the actual problem isn't obvious from the code posted in the question. The problem is, I don't see how this can be improved, since the problem is caused by invisible whitespace characters which I'm not even sure will make it through the Stack Overflow question markup.

But it's definitely a valuable question so I'd hate for it to be deleted [**EDIT**: ok, I accept that this is unlikely to happen, as per @Servy's answer. However, that's not the real thrust of my question here. I don't believe the question deserves even to be closed, but I don't know how to improve it to make it more likely to be reopened]

Would it be appropriate for me to edit the question to make it more palatable? And if so, any suggestions on how to do it? Would adding a note in the question itself to the effect of "I know you can't see them, but there are magic non-breaking whitespace characters in there" help?

Or is it truly off-topic? I really hope not.

Comment: _"...note in the question itself to the effect of "I know you can't see them, but there are magic non-breaking whitespace characters in there" help?"_ No. This would be putting _the answer_ in the question, since the answer was basically "You copied the code and it had magic non-breaking whitespace characters in there." As for if it's off-topic... I don't feel like it is, as this could be truly confusing to a lot of people, but at the same time...

Comment: @Kendra right, but if you can't paste the magic characters themselves into the question, what else can be done to make this on-topic? Because at it's heart, it really is. And even if you can paste the magic characters into the question (I haven't checked this btw), they won't be visible, so unless you already know the answer, you won't guess it by looking at the code.

Comment: The way the user explained the situation pretty well covered it- They don't see the symbols, but they seem to get inserted into the code when it's being run. Which pretty much says it's there, but decoded so the user in question cannot see it. Saying in the question that it's in there makes it look like the user already knows what's going on- Considering having those in there is the entire problem with the code.

Comment: @Kendra sure - I'm actually agreeing with you here - let's agree that my suggested edit is inappropriate. But I still feel like there should be a way for this question to become a first-class citizen again since it is clearly useful, and to my mind clearly on-topic apart from what amounts to a technicality.

Answer (score 2):

It has an upvoted answer, and it is an upvoted question, so it's not going to be automatically delete ever, and it has no deletion votes, so I don't see any reason to assume that it would get deleted at any point in the future.

Comment: Interesting point. I guess I'm going to have to go and read some more about the purpose of the limbo of closed questions... I'm sure I'm not the first person to think this feels a bit weird. It's off-topic but it's useful, so we'll keep it around, but it has to sleep in the barn...

Comment: Keeping it closed will also help not to attract more users to give trivial answers about that question. It's better than give it a lock.

Comment: @CupawnTae Closing stops answering, and it *allows* for deletion, but doesn't necessarily mean that the post *will* be deleted, just that it *can* be, if additional circumstances are also met.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ is that a worry here any more than an open question? Why would it attract trivial answers particularly, especially when it has an upvoted and accepted answer?

Comment: @CupawnTae Well, being closed, one *cannot* answer it.  Go ahead and try to post an answer; you won't be able to until it's reopened.

Comment: @Servy sorry, I meant "why does it need to have that protection?" I don't see that this question would attract trivial answers any more than any other

Comment: @CupawnTae It's common experience, that this kind of questions will draw for the trivial solution being answered multiple times. Mostly by low rep users, who feel happy to find something they can answer. Locking will outweigh _low rep users_ answers, while closing will ensure that Q&A is left in that (useful) state it is, without any additional noise.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what kind of question do you mean though? The question is pretty specific about what's happening (`&nbsp;`s in the output) and doesn't particularly scream for trivial answers as far as I can see.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ also, if that's the biggest advantage of closing it, surely it would actually be better to reopen and lock it?

Comment: @CupawnTae Locking would, in addition to preventing answers, also prevent edits, and voting.  Why would you prefer that?

Comment: @Servy it's not that I would prefer that, it's the purist in me saying if it should be locked, lock it (not that I believe so). If it should be closed, close it. If it should be protected, protect it. (Again I'll fully admit I'm not very familiar with the nitty-gritty of the various "limbo" states of questions). I was questioning πάνταῥεῖ's point about stopping trivial answers - I don't see that as the question's fault even if it's true, and therefore I don't see it as a good reason for closing the question